# SWT Component for choose file only from workspace

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I work with SWT and Eclipse's plugin. I need choose file only from workspace. I founded component for choose directory in workspace, component for choose file in file system, but i have not found component for choose file from workspace.

Now I'm using `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog` and set filter `setFilterPath(Platform.getLocation().toOSString())`. But the user can choose other file not from workspace. They should only be able to set files from within the workspace.

Answer (score 5):

Thank for answers. I create own component and use it. Also i add filter for choose files.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IContainer;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ElementTreeSelectionDialog;
import org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ISelectionStatusValidator;
import org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchLabelProvider;

/**
 * @author Alexey Prybytkouski
 */
public class ResourceFileSelectionDialog extends ElementTreeSelectionDialog {

    private String[] extensions;

    private static ITreeContentProvider contentProvider = new ITreeContentProvider() {
        public Object[] getChildren(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof IContainer) {
                try {
                    return ((IContainer) element).members();
                }
                catch (CoreException e) {
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Object getParent(Object element) {
            return ((IResource) element).getParent();
        }

        public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
            return element instanceof IContainer;
        }

        public Object[] getElements(Object input) {
            return (Object[]) input;
        }

        public void dispose() {
        }

        public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        }
    };

    private static final IStatus OK = new Status(IStatus.OK, PLUGIN_ID, 0, "", null);
    private static final IStatus ERROR = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, PLUGIN_ID, 0, "", null);

    /*
     * Validator
     */
    private ISelectionStatusValidator validator = new ISelectionStatusValidator() {
        public IStatus validate(Object[] selection) {
            return selection.length == 1 && selection[0] instanceof IFile
                    && checkExtension(((IFile) selection[0]).getFileExtension()) ? OK : ERROR;
        }
    };

    public ResourceFileSelectionDialog(String title, String message, String[] type) {
        this(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), WorkbenchLabelProvider.getDecoratingWorkbenchLabelProvider(),
                contentProvider);
        this.extensions = type;

        setTitle(title);
        setMessage(message);

        setInput(computeInput());
        setValidator(validator);
    }

    public ResourceFileSelectionDialog(Shell parent, ILabelProvider labelProvider, ITreeContentProvider contentProvider) {
        super(parent, labelProvider, contentProvider);
    }

    /*
     * Show projects
     */
    private Object[] computeInput() {
        /*
         * Refresh projects tree.
         */
        IProject[] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
        for (int i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            try {
                projects[i].refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_ONE, null);
        } catch (CoreException e) {
        }
        List<IProject> openProjects = new ArrayList<IProject>(projects.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            if (projects[i].isOpen()) {
                openProjects.add(projects[i]);
            }
        }
        return openProjects.toArray();
    }

    /*
     * Check file extension
     */
    private boolean checkExtension(String name) {
        if (name.equals("*")) {
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
            if (extensions[i].equals(name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and call:

```
ResourceFileSelectionDialog dialog = new ResourceFileSelectionDialog("Title", "Message", new String[] { "properties" });
dialog.open();
```

[image: expample1]

[image: example2]

Comment: What makes this better than using the simple solution that @sambi reddy gives?

Comment: The answer given by @sambi does not show how to add elements to the tree, which in this answer is done via setInput(computeInput());. Further, this answer also shows hot to personalise the dialog: title, message, validator, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. With this you should be able to browse through workspace.

You need to add `eclipse.ui`  and `resources` plugins as dependencies.

```
ElementTreeSelectionDialog dialog = new ElementTreeSelectionDialog(
    Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), 
    new WorkbenchLabelProvider(), 
    new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider());

dialog.open();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know any SWT Component that provides you that kind of control over user interaction.

So, I think the best solution here is:

You can develop a window that reads the content of the folder, display it to the user, and give him no navegation possibiliites other than subfolders of the root folder (workspace folder in your case).

See this examples:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecgui1/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecgui2/

Comment: At the examples, see the FileTreeContentProvider class. There you can implement the location filter.