# SWT - Workspace and EPackage Registry browse

Tags: java, swt, jface

How can I implement `Workspace Browse` and `EPackages Browse` in `SWT / jface`?
The below code browse File System not Workspace.

```
Button button = new Button(grpModelProperties, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Browse Workspace...");
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(getShell(), SWT.NULL);
String path = dialog.open();
if (path != null) {
File file = new File(path);
if (file.isFile())
displayFiles(new String[] { file.toString()});
else
displayFiles(file.list());
}
}
});
```

I also tried the solution presented in [SWT Component for choose file only from workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750712/swt-component-for-choose-file-only-from-workspace) by @sambi reddy but I have the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/util/NLS
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.SelectionDialog.<clinit>(SelectionDialog.java:55)
at mypackage.FrontPage.createControl(FrontPage.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:705)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:792)
at mypackage.ReservationWizard.main(ReservationWizard.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.util.NLS
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 21 more
```

I also don't have an idea about EPackages browse.

**edit:**
When I run the below code, no entries available although workspace has projects:

```
Button button2 = new Button(grpModelProperties1, SWT.PUSH);
button2.setText("Browse Workspace...");
final GridData button2Data = new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, true, true);
button2.setLayoutData(button2Data);
button2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e2) {
    ElementTreeSelectionDialog dialog = new ElementTreeSelectionDialog(
    Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), 
    new WorkbenchLabelProvider(), 
    new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider());
    dialog.open();
}
});
```

Comment: If you are talking about the Eclipse workspace then you must use an Eclipse plugin, the workspace is not available to a plain Java program. The answers you link to will work in a plugin. I have no idea what you mean by EPackages browse.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you so much. Yes, my means is Eclipse Workspace. When I use Eclipse plugin and that code, the files not shown. It says no entries available. Do you know what can I do?
My mean is EMF Registry (Metamodels that are registred in eclipse).They are also shown in Window-> show view -> other -> Epsilon -> Epackage Registry or in the Run Configuration of ATL and Epsilon languages in eclipse.

Comment: When you test your plugin a new workspace is created which is empty. You will have to add test projects to that workspace. I don't use Eclipse Epsilon so I can't comment on that.

Comment: @greg-449 I ran the plugin as an eclipse application and so tested it in new eclipse. The workspace of new eclipse also has projects. However, they are not shown.

Comment: Run what code? Show us exactly what you are running.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the Eclipse workspace in an Eclipse plugin, it is not available in a plain Java app because of the large amount of initialization that is required.

In your `ElementTreeSelectionDialog` dialog you must call `setInput` to tell the dialog about the elements to be displayed:

```
ElementTreeSelectionDialog dialog = new ElementTreeSelectionDialog(
                Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(),
                new WorkbenchLabelProvider(),
                new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider());

dialog.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot());

dialog.open();
```

This displays the entire workspace, by changing the input to a IProject or IFolder you can restrict the display to part of the workspace.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I get the string path of selected file to show in the textbox?

Comment: What textbox? If you have a new question ask a New Question.

Comment: In this question, how can I get the string path of selected file?

Comment: Call `getFirstResult` to get the first selected item or `getResult` to get array of selected items.

Comment: How can I restrict it to only root elements (projects or folders) that containes ".ecore" file shown?

Comment: @any If you have a question please ask a new question. Show your existing code.

Comment: Ok. This is a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187588/restrict-the-elementtreeselectiondialog